# PowerShell foreach loop with same date for all iterations

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach

I'm trying to parse .txt file through directories (this part is ok).
These files are reports and contains lists of serial Numbers, I succeed to retrieve the good list too.
Each file contains many serial and one date, I'd like to construct an array where the first column will be serial number and the 2nd one the repeated date, and it's where I failed.
How to repeat this date for all the serials and arrange it in a CSV file?

File to parse example: Filname: [Calibrage - Vérification][Sonde T Cryo][17-01-2019  14h51mn24].txt

```
Début de <<Calibrage / Vérification>>,  <<Sonde T Cryo>> Le 17-01-2019  14h51mn24

******************************************************************************
** Conditions de mesures                                                    **
******************************************************************************
Nom de l'opérateur :  AF
Condition de mesures : 
    Température :  21°C
    Hygrométrie :  40%HR
    Préssion atmosphérique :  980 HPA
Commentaire :  NIM F85 / NIM F317 / NIM F100 / NOUVELLES SONDES NUMT 3M. 12199


Période de mesure = 15s
Nombre de point de mesure = 5

******************************************************************************
** Mesure Sonde en mode VERIFICATION (Moyenne)                              **
******************************************************************************
        Mesure Brut                 Moyenne
Palier 1  (17-01-2019  23h51mn24)
Sonde 01    -18,263 -18,263 -18,263 -18,293 -18,263     -18,269
Sonde 02    -18,351 -18,361 -18,371 -18,341 -18,351     -18,355
Sonde 03    -18,336 -18,336 -18,326 -18,346 -18,336     -18,336
Sonde 05    -18,357 -18,357 -18,357 -18,357 -18,337     -18,353

******************************************************************************
** Contrôle d’anomalie de la mesure                                         **
** Ecart max toléré entre la sonde et la Ref est de +-10°C                  **
******************************************************************************
Aucune anomalie constatée



******************************************************************************
** Les appareils ci-dessous sont Calibrés Et Vérifiés.                      **
******************************************************************************
Le seuil de tolerance est : +/- 0,2°C

Sonde n°01 [ AE190150013]           Sonde n°02 [ AE190150014]           
Sonde n°03 [ AE190150017]           Sonde n°05 [ AE190150018]           
Sonde n°06 [ AE190150015]           Sonde n°07 [ AE190150020]           
Sonde n°08 [ AE190150012]           Sonde n°09 [ AE190150016]           
Sonde n°10 [ AE190150011]           Sonde n°11 [ AE190150019]           
Sonde n°20 [ AE190150001]           Sonde n°21 [ AE190150002]           


******************************************************************************
** Les appareils ci-dessous n'ont pas passés le test de calibrage.          **
******************************************************************************
Sonde n°04 [            ]           Sonde n°22 [            ]           
Sonde n°23 [            ]           Sonde n°24 [            ]           
Sonde n°25 [            ]           Sonde n°26 [            ]           
Sonde n°27 [            ]           Sonde n°28 [            ]           
Sonde n°29 [            ]           Sonde n°30 [            ]           
Sonde n°31 [            ]           Sonde n°32 [            ]           

Fin de <<Calibrage / Vérification>>,  <<Sonde T Cryo>> Le 18-01-2019  04h52mn54
```

What I'd like to get is:
date at the first line
and only Serials between "Les appareils ci-dessous sont Calibrés Et Vérifiés. " and "Les appareils ci-dessous n'ont pas passés le test de calibrage."

```
        $data = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DEV\2019\2019_01 Janvier\*.txt'

[char[]]$replace = '!@#$%^&*(){}[]":;,<>/|\+=`~ '''
$regex = ($replace | % {[regex]::Escape($_)}) -join '|'
Get-ChildItem $data -recurse |
  Where-Object { $_.Name -match $RegEx} |
    Rename-Item -NewName {$_.Name -replace $RegEx, '_'}

(Get-ChildItem $data -recurse).FullName |
  Foreach-Object {
   (Get-Content $_ -Raw).
        Replace('** Les appareils ci-dessous sont Calibrés Et Vérifiés.                      **','§').
        Replace("Le seuil de tolerance est:+/-0,2°C",' ').
        Replace("Leseuildetoleranceest:+/-0,2°C",'').
        Replace("Le seuil de tolerance est:+/-0,3°C",' ').
        Replace("Leseuildetoleranceest:+/-0,3°C",'').
        Replace("** Les appareils ci-dessous n'ont pas passés le test de calibrage.          **",'§').
        Replace('*','').
        Replace('n°','').
        Replace('Sonde','').
        Replace(' ','').
        Replace('   ','') |
        Set-Content $_
  }


$folders = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DEV\2019\2019_01 Janvier'
$files = Get-ChildItem -Path $Folders -Include *.txt -Force -Recurse 
foreach ($File in $Files) {
        Foreach ($FileContent in $File) {
        $FileContent = Get-Content -Path $File
        $date = [regex]::matches($File,'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}').value

         }
        $serial_temp = $FileContent -ireplace "^[^\[]*\[\s*","" -ireplace "\s*\][^\[]*\[\s*","`r`n" -ireplace "\]" 
        $serial = [regex]::Matches($serial_temp, '§([^/)]+)§') |ForEach-Object { $_.Groups[1].Value }
        [System.String]$Text = $serial
$Keys = $serial -ireplace "^[^\[]*\[\s*","" -ireplace "\s*\][^\[]*\[\s*","`r`n" -ireplace "\]" 

    Write-Host $Serial $date    

    }
```

Comment: What do you need the `$Keys` variable for?

Comment: Is the date part of the file NAME or the CONTENT?

Comment: you're right not really needed...

Comment: date is part of the content, and I succeed to retrieve it

Comment: Weird, because you are getting it using a regex on a **FileInfo** object at that point, not the content of the file you start to get in the line below... Shouldn't work.

Comment: To help you, show us part of the .txt file you are parsing. A tip already: build your object in the same loop as where you retrieve the date and serials and add it to your `$OutArray` there.

Comment: The code you posted is incomplete (last two closing curly brackets have no matching opening construct). Please do not introduce new bugs when asking a question. Create a [mcve], test-run it to verify that it exposes the behaviour you're trying to debug, then copy/paste *that* code into your question.

Comment: I edited the question

Comment: I publish the write-host result that I need to arrange

Comment: @webalive I expressly asked you to test-run your [mcve] before posting. Your updated code cannot possibly produce the result you claim it does. Come back after you learned following simple instructions.

Comment: Please note that txt filename also include and time. Many other information in the file. I replace some sentences with a special char to delimit the text i néed and extract it. It s why you see thèse regex. Thanks  @Theo to noticed me about I get date before content in the filename

Comment: What you are now showing us is _NOT_ an example of the file, but a list you have made up from three files, leaving out everything but the desired lines.. This way we can never tell is for instance your regexes would work or not.. PLEASE, show us the (sanitized if need be) **real** content of one of those files if you want to get help on your code.

Comment: Hi all, sorry for late reply., I updated the post with the original file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now that you have given us an example to work with, I think this will help you.

The code parses the file and exports a CSV file with four columns: `Serial`, `Date`, `Model` and a 4th column to show if the 'Sonde' passed or failed the calibration test called `Status`.
(you may leave that one out of course, but then you might think all equipment worked ok..)

```
$folders = 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\DEV\2019\2019_01 Janvier'
$files   = Get-ChildItem -Path $folders -Filter '*.txt' -Force -Recurse 
$result  = @()

foreach ($file in $files) {
    # read the file as single string (-Raw) and split into 3 text blocks
    $content = Get-Content -Path $file.FullName -Raw

    # get the date from the file name
    $date = [regex]::Matches($file.Name,'\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}').Value
    if (!$date -and $content -match '\d{2}-\d{2}-\d{4}') {
        # if date from file name failed, try and get it from the content
        $date = $matches[0]
    }
    else {
        # if still not date is found, take it from the file itself
        $date = '{0:dd-MM-yyyy}' -f $file.LastWriteTime
    }

    # get the model number at the end of the 'Commentaire' line if any
    $model = if ($content -match 'Commentaire\s*:.*\s(\d+)[\r?\n]') { $matches[1] } else { '' }

    # split the content into text blocks and select the last two
    $content  = $content -split 'Les appareils ci-dessous' | Select-Object -Last 2

    $re = [regex]'\[\s*(?<serial>\w+)'
    foreach ($block in $content) {
        if ($block -match 'Calibrés Et Vérifiés') {
            $match = $re.Match($block)
            while ($match.Success) {
                $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Serial = $match.Groups['serial'].Value
                    Date   = $date
                    Model  = $model
                    Status = 'Passed'
                }
                $match = $match.NextMatch()
            } 
        }
        elseif ($block -match "n'ont pas passés") {
            $match = $re.Match($block)
            while ($match.Success) {
                $result += [PSCustomObject]@{
                    Serial = $match.Groups['serial'].Value
                    Date   = $date
                    Model  = $model
                    Status = 'Failed'
                }
                $match = $match.NextMatch()
            } 
        }
    }
}

$result | Export-Csv "C:\Users\user\DEV\somefile.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```

Using your example file, the resulting CSV file would contain:

> ```
> "Serial","Date","Model","Status"
> "AE190150013","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150014","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150017","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150018","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150015","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150020","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150012","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150016","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150011","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150019","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150001","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> "AE190150002","17-01-2019","12199","Passed"
> ```

Hope that answers your question

Comment: Hi Theo, thank you very much for this, your approach really helps.
Do you think there's a way to retrieve the model number at the end of "commentaire" line (12199) ? it should be 5 Numbers or 5" "2 as xxxxx or xxxxx xx ?

Comment: @webalive Ok, although this was a requirement not in the original question, I have edited the code to also include the `Model` in the output.

Comment: thanks for this too… exactly what I'm looking for. have a good day.